# Most Pythonic way to print *at most* some number of decimal places

Tags: python, floating-point, string-formatting

I want to format a list of floating-point numbers with at most, say, 2 decimal places. But, I don't want trailing zeros, and I don't want trailing decimal points.

So, for example, `4.001` => `4`, `4.797` => `4.8`, `8.992` => `8.99`, `13.577` => `13.58`.

The simple solution is <s>`('%.2f' % f).rstrip('.0')`</s>`('%.2f' % f).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')`. But, that looks rather ugly and seems fragile. Any nicer solutions, maybe with some magical format flags?

Comment: Am I missing the point here, or what about the `round()` function: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round

Comment: Though, I have to say, I'm not a huge fan of solutions that involve `round` simply because I am nervous I'll get `1.1000000000009962` as an output someday.

Comment: Aarrgh, it's not a duplicate! I don't want trailing `.0`. The other question permits that.

Comment: @nneonneo I believe `int()` will get rid of the `.0`, but use in caution as it will get rid of any other decimal places (so perhaps an if/else statement?)

Comment: @Haidro: ...now that's just getting icky. I was hoping I didn't need an `if/else`, or I would just condition on the `'.%2f' % f` or something. (Still weirdly difficult to have a nice solution...I'm really used to things being really easy in Python)

Comment: Och, someone pointed out that `('%.2f' % f).rstrip('.0')` mangles `1000.0` into `1`. So now we need `.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')`...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to separate the `0` and the `.` stripping; that way you won't ever strip away the natural `0`.

Alternatively, use the `format()` function, but that really comes down to the same thing:

```
format(f, '.2f').rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

Some tests:

```
>>> def formatted(f): return format(f, '.2f').rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
... 
>>> formatted(0.0)
'0'
>>> formatted(4.797)
'4.8'
>>> formatted(4.001)
'4'
>>> formatted(13.577)
'13.58'
>>> formatted(0.000000000000000000001)
'0'
>>> formatted(10000000000)
'10000000000'
```

Comment: +1: I guess this is the conclusion I came to independently. I was hoping there was a nicer solution, but there simply might not be one. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

The `g` formatter limits the output to `n` significant digits, dropping trailing zeroes:

```
>>> "{:.3g}".format(1.234)
'1.23'
>>> "{:.3g}".format(1.2)
'1.2'
>>> "{:.3g}".format(1)
'1'
```

Comment: You can use the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) if all you have is one `{}` template. e.g. `format(f, '.3g')`. This even works correctly for 0.

Comment: Almost...except that it prints *at most three digits*, rather than *at most two decimal places*. (Example: `'{:.3g}'.format(13.468)` prints `13.5` rather than `13.47`)

Comment: Ah, and it also does the wrong thing when exponents are involved.

Comment: OK, I guess you could do `"{0:.{1}g}".format(13.468, 2+len(str(int(13.468))))`, but that's not really Pythonic, I guess :)

Answer (score 5):

In general working with String[s] can be slow.
However, this is another solution:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> precision = Decimal('.00')
>>> Decimal('4.001').quantize(precision).normalize()
Decimal('4')
>>> Decimal('4.797').quantize(precision).normalize()
Decimal('4.8')
>>> Decimal('8.992').quantize(precision).normalize()
Decimal('8.99')
>>> Decimal('13.577').quantize(precision).normalize()
Decimal('13.58')
```

You may find more info here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html