# How to estimate how much memory a Pandas' DataFrame will need?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been wondering... If I am reading, say, a 400MB csv file into a pandas dataframe (using read_csv or read_table), is there any way to guesstimate how much memory this will need? Just trying to get a better feel of data frames and  memory...

Comment: You could always look at the process & it's memory usage for a single file. If you're running linux, try `top` and then `Shift + M` to sort my memory usage.

Comment: I feel I should advertise this [open pandas issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3871).

Comment: I have a large dataframe with 4 million rows. I discovered that its empty subset `x=df.loc[[]]` takes `0.1` seconds to get computed (to extract zero rows) and, furthermore, takes hundreds of megabytes of memory, just as the original dataframe, probably because of some copying underneath.

Comment: new link for the [old post](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/a-new-high-performance-memory-efficient-file-parser-engine-for-pandas/) by the pandas lead developer

Answer (score 185):

[`df.memory_usage()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.memory_usage.html) will return how many bytes each column occupies:

```
>>> df.memory_usage()

Row_ID            20906600
Household_ID      20906600
Vehicle           20906600
Calendar_Year     20906600
Model_Year        20906600
...
```

To include indexes, pass `index=True`.

So to get overall memory consumption:

```
>>> df.memory_usage(index=True).sum()
731731000
```

Also, passing `deep=True` will enable a more accurate memory usage report, that accounts for the full usage of the contained objects.

This is because memory usage does not include memory consumed by elements that are not components of the array if `deep=False` (default case).

Comment: is the sum of all the columns' memory usages really the impact on memory usage? I can imagine there to be more overhead.

Comment: You really also want `deep=True`

Comment: The sum of df.memory_usage() does not equal sys.getsizeof(df) ! There are many overheads. As smci mentioned, You need `deep=True`

Comment: FYI, `memory_usage()` returns the memory usage in bytes (as you would expect).

Comment: Why such a huge difference between with/without deep=True?

Answer (score 147):

Here's a comparison of the different methods - `sys.getsizeof(df)` is simplest.

For this example, `df` is a dataframe with 814 rows, 11 columns (2 ints, 9 objects) - read from a 427kb shapefile

#### sys.getsizeof(df)

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(df)
(gives results in bytes)
462456
```

#### df.memory_usage()

```
>>> df.memory_usage()
...
(lists each column at 8 bytes/row)

>>> df.memory_usage().sum()
71712
(roughly rows * cols * 8 bytes)

>>> df.memory_usage(deep=True)
(lists each column's full memory usage)

>>> df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
(gives results in bytes)
462432
```

#### df.info()

Prints dataframe info to stdout. Technically these are kibibytes (KiB), not kilobytes - as the docstring says, "Memory usage is shown in human-readable units (base-2 representation)." So to get bytes would multiply by 1024, e.g. 451.6 KiB = 462,438 bytes.

```
>>> df.info()
...
memory usage: 70.0+ KB

>>> df.info(memory_usage='deep')
...
memory usage: 451.6 KB
```

Comment: What object or module doe the `g`  code above refer to?

Comment: @zozo woops - was a typo - fixed

Comment: Hi @BrianBurns sys.getsizeof(df) is giving memory value in kb ? or mb?

Comment: @RahulKumarSingh it's in bytes - will note in answer

Comment: I use `df.info(memory_usage="deep")`, it returns "392.6 MB", whereas `sys.getsizeof(df)` and `df.memory_usage(index=True, deep=True).sum()` both return approximately "411718016" (~ 411MB). Can you please explain why the 3 results are not consistent ? thanks

Comment: @Catbuilts hmm, maybe df.info doesn't include the index and the others do? What does `df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()` return?

Comment: @BrianBurns: `df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()` returns nearly the same with `df.memory_usage(index=True, deep=True).sum()`. in my case, the `index` doesnt take much memory. Interestingly enough, I found that `411718016/1024/1024 = 392.6`, so  `df.info(memory_usage="deep")` may use `2^10` to convert *byte* to *MB*, which makes me confused. Thanks for your help anyway :D.

Comment: @Catbuilts Ah, that explains it! `df.info` is returning mebibytes (2^10), not megabytes (10^6) - will amend the answer.

Comment: just a reminder. it would be nice to accept an answer as a courtesy to the people who helped you. I believe this is the most comprehensive one.

Answer (score 58):

I thought I would bring some more data to the discussion.

I ran a series of tests on this issue.

By using the python `resource` package I got the memory usage of my process.

And by writing the csv into a `StringIO` buffer, I could easily measure the size of it in bytes.

I ran two experiments, each one creating 20 dataframes of increasing sizes between 10,000 lines and 1,000,000 lines. Both having 10 columns.

In the first experiment I used only floats in my dataset.

This is how the memory increased in comparison to the csv file as a function of the number of lines. (Size in Megabytes)

[image: Memory and CSV size in Megabytes as a function of the number of rows with float entries]

The second experiment I had the same approach, but the data in the dataset consisted of only short strings.

[image: Memory and CSV size in Megabytes as a function of the number of rows with string entries]

It seems that the relation of the size of the csv and the size of the dataframe can vary quite a lot, but the size in memory will always be bigger by a factor of 2-3 (for the frame sizes in this experiment)

I would love to complete this answer with more experiments, please comment if you want me to try something special.

Comment: What is your y axis?

Comment: max_rss and csv size on disk in megabytes

Answer (score 32):

You have to do this in reverse.

```
In [4]: DataFrame(randn(1000000,20)).to_csv('test.csv')

In [5]: !ls -ltr test.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 users 399508276 Aug  6 16:55 test.csv
```

Technically memory is about this (which includes the indexes)

```
In [16]: df.values.nbytes + df.index.nbytes + df.columns.nbytes
Out[16]: 168000160
```

So 168MB in memory with a 400MB file, 1M rows of 20 float columns

```
DataFrame(randn(1000000,20)).to_hdf('test.h5','df')

!ls -ltr test.h5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 users 168073944 Aug  6 16:57 test.h5
```

MUCH more compact when written as a binary HDF5 file

```
In [12]: DataFrame(randn(1000000,20)).to_hdf('test.h5','df',complevel=9,complib='blosc')

In [13]: !ls -ltr test.h5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 users 154727012 Aug  6 16:58 test.h5
```

The data was random, so compression doesn't help too much

Comment: That is very clever! Any idea how to measure the memory you need to read the file using `read_csv`?

Comment: No idea how to measure AS you read; IIRC it can be up to 2x the final memory needed to hold the data (from wes's article), but I think he brought it down to a constant + final memory

Comment: Ah, I need to re-read, I remembered 2x being some convenient theoretical min for a certain algorithm, if it's even less that's coool.

Comment: You can use [`iotop`](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) like `top`/`htop` for watching (in real time) IO performance.

Comment: `nbytes` will be a gross underestimate if you have e.g. strings in a dataframe.

Comment: You probably want to note that `!ls` is a `!magic` that only works under Jupyter.

Comment: What/who is Wes's Article?

Answer (score 14):

Yes there is. Pandas will store your data in 2 dimensional numpy `ndarray` structures grouping them by dtypes. `ndarray` is basically a raw C array of data with a small header. So you can estimate it's size just by multiplying the size of the `dtype` it contains with the dimensions of the array.

For example: if you have 1000 rows with 2 `np.int32` and 5 `np.float64` columns, your DataFrame will have one 2x1000 `np.int32` array and one 5x1000 `np.float64` array which is:

4bytes*2*1000 + 8bytes*5*1000 = 48000 bytes

Comment: @AndyHayden What do you mean the construction cost? The size of an instance of `DataFrame`?

Comment: Thanks Victor! @Andy - Any idea how big the construction cost is?

Comment: It's not including, but `pandas` have a very efficient implementation of `read_table` in Cython (it's much better than the numpy's loadtxt) so I assume that it parsers and stores the data directly into the `ndarray`.

Comment: @PhillipCloud you have to build it, that takes memory.. I seem to remember twice the size being mentioned?...

Answer (score 10):

If you know the `dtype`s of your array then you can directly compute the number of bytes that it will take to store your data + some for the Python objects themselves. A useful attribute of `numpy` arrays is `nbytes`. You can get the number of bytes from the arrays in a pandas `DataFrame` by doing

```
nbytes = sum(block.values.nbytes for block in df.blocks.values())
```

`object` dtype arrays store 8 bytes per object (object dtype arrays store a pointer to an opaque `PyObject`), so if you have strings in your csv you need to take into account that `read_csv` will turn those into `object` dtype arrays and adjust your calculations accordingly.

EDIT:

See the [`numpy` scalar types page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types) for more details on the `object` `dtype`. Since only a reference is stored you need to take into account the size of the object in the array as well. As that page says, object arrays are somewhat similar to Python `list` objects.

Comment: Thanks Phillip! Just to clarify - for a string we would need 8 bytes for a pointer to a string object, plus the actual string object?

Comment: Yes, for any object type you'll need an 8 byte pointer + size(object)

Comment: Suggest df.blocks.values()  It looks like df.blocks is now a dict

Answer (score 8):

This I believe this gives the in-memory size any object in python. Internals need to be checked with regard to pandas and numpy

```
>>> import sys
#assuming the dataframe to be df 
>>> sys.getsizeof(df) 
59542497
```

Answer (score 5):

To print human readable results you can try this:

```
suffixes = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB']
def humansize(nbytes):
    i = 0
    while nbytes >= 1024 and i < len(suffixes)-1:
        nbytes /= 1024.
        i += 1
    f = ('%.2f' % nbytes).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
    return '%s %s' % (f, suffixes[i])

df.memory_usage(index=True, deep=True).apply(humansize)
# Index  128 B
# a      571.72 MB
# b      687.78 MB
# c      521.6 MB
# dtype: object

humansize(df.memory_usage(index=True, deep=True).sum())
# 1.74 GB
```

Code adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14996816/3552975) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32970117/3552975) answer.