# Where does pandas.read_gbq() 'save' the query when conducted in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

I am downloading a dataset from Google BigQuery using pandas like so

`df = pd.read_gbq(query, location="US"...)`

and it tells me it is downloading. But where is the data saved? 
I need to know before calling in the heavy loads...

Comment: Clarifying question: are you asking where pandas stores the temporary file while it's being downloaded or where the final result is once it's done?

Comment: now all data is in your variable df   , print it  ...if you want put it into csv try with df.to_csv('myfile.csv')

Comment: print(df.head(10))

Comment: I wonder where pandas stores the temporary file BEFORE I save it to .csv etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has an object allocator that is responsible for allocating memory within the object memory area. It directly uses the memory of the machine where Jupyter is running to store the DataFrame you obtain from your ***pd.read_gbq*** call. Check [CPython’s Memory Management](https://realpython.com/python-memory-management/) for more more insights on this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089667/how-to-estimate-how-much-memory-a-pandas-dataframe-will-need) you have different methods to estimate the size in memory that this DataFrame will need.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, my upvote will not be displayed, since I am new.