# Dask-cudf with single GPU

Tags: python, csv, dask, cudf

I am trying to read 12 GB CSV file. 
If I am trying to read with CUDF it is giving a memory error

> MemoryError: std::bad_alloc: CUDA error at:
> /usr/local/envs/bsql/include/rmm/mr/device/cuda_memory_resource.hpp:69:
> cudaErrorMemoryAllocation out of memory

But when I try to read with dask_cudf with `LocalCUDACluster` it is not giving any memory issue.
My question is if both are using a single GPU then why one is having a memory issues and other is not?

Comment: `dask_cudf.read_csv` returns a lazy object that has not yet been evaluated-- do you still see this memory error when you call `compute()`?

Comment: I do not see memory error in dask cudf even after compute()
I had run df.count().compute() and it executed perfectly
The issue is only with cudf

Answer (score 1):

In the same way Dask is able to take advantage of multiple cores on a single CPU, Dask-cuDF can take advantage of multiple cores on a single GPU. Therefore, if your dataset takes up more memory than you can fit in a single GPU, you should use Dask-cuDF instead of cuDF (see the RAPIDS docs [here](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/nightly/user_guide/10min.html#When-to-use-cuDF-and-Dask-cuDF)).

Comment: But my dataset is only 12 GB and GPU memory is 40 GB.

Comment: Though the size of the CSV is 12 GB on disk, it will be much larger when loaded in memory. Exactly how much is dataset-specific, but [here is one comparison as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31543407/17015034). Dask-cuDF doesn't need to load the entire dataset in memory at once as cuDF does.