# How to find the estimated size of dataset prior to writing it to disk

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have a large dataset (csv file ) in my memory. I am reading dataset in my python environment. I have to split the dataset when it reaches 1 GB. So, my initial dataset is around 1.8 GB when I read. So, accordingly, I should have two datasets, one with 1 GB of size and the other with remaining.

How to do it ?

The solution should considered time and space complexity both

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to estimate how much memory a Pandas' DataFrame will need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089667/how-to-estimate-how-much-memory-a-pandas-dataframe-will-need)

Comment: yes , to a certain extent only. I found one strange thing. When I am reading it using memory_usage() function (sum(data.memory_usage(deep=True))) and adding all the numbers , it is leading to around 4.9 GB. However , the actual file is just of 1.3 GB ?