# comparing large csv files

Tags: python, pandas

Which method is more efficient for comparing two large (8GB & 5GB) `csv` files? The output should contain every id that is not in `file1`.

The data is a single column with GUIDs.

Method 1:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)

df = df.merge(df1, on=['id'], how="outer", indicator=True).query('_merge=="left_only"')
df['id'].to_csv(output_path, index=False)
```

Method 2:

```
with open(file1, 'r') as t1:
    file = set(t1)

with open(file, 'r') as t2, open(output_path, 'w') as outFile:
    for line in t2:
        if line not in file:
            outFile.write(line)
```

Comment: What type of efficiency are you looking for? Is it about speed of execution, memory usage or something else?

Comment: Speed and memory usage

Comment: Seems like you have two horses... race them?

Comment: Also what are those ids? This may matter when considering how to store them... (if they are numeric you will use less memory if you transform the strings into ints

Comment: The ids are GUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by efficiency? Certainly two major differences are as follows:

1. The first method, which pandas uses, needs to have all the data in memory. So you will need an amount of available memory to hold the data from the two csv files (note: 5+8gb may not be enough, but it will depend on the type of data in the csv files).
2. The second method takes advantage of python's generators, and reads
   the file line by line, loading into memory one line at a time.

So if you have the memory available to load the data into memory, it will certainly be faster to load all the data into memory and do the operations on the data in memory.

If you don't have enough memory available, the second method works but is definitely slower. a good compromise might be to read the file by chunk, loading into memory an amount of data that your hardware can handle.

**Extras**

To estimate the memory space used by your datframe you can read this nice post:

- [How to estimate how much memory a Pandas' DataFrame will need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089667/how-to-estimate-how-much-memory-a-pandas-dataframe-will-need)

Here you can find approndments explaining how to read a file by chunk, with or without pandas

- [How do I read a large csv file with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas)
- [Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)

Comment: Your point is correct but I think you might be wrong about pandas needing 13GB... The csv is stored as text (probably utf8 so one byte per character). Pandas instead will store numbers as some form of int (32 or 64 bit) so the sizes will not match (pandas will store it in less memory than the csv)

Comment: Ciao Matteo, I have added other considerations to my answer

Comment: Yes you are right, it also depends on the type of data contained in the csvs. However the concept does not change, whether it is 10gb or 32gb is all relative to the HW you have. The important thing is to know what to do (and how to approach the problem ) when not all the data can fit in memory :)

Comment: Definitely, you are 100% correct. Just wanted to clarify this small point. Your explanation is still valid

Comment: Of course, you were right to point it out to me.

Comment: I'm running the first method for 7 hours without any results that's why I'm considering the second method.

Comment: Ok, so you are asking too much of your hardware. It would be interesting to know if the execution is stuck on loading into memory, or if it is stuck on merge.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you'll have to run multiple times, you can just wrap them with `start = time.time()` at the beginning and `execution_time = time.time() - start` at the end to compare speed. To compare memory, you can check out this package, [`memory_profiler`](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler)

Comment: When using time to compute execution metrics `time.perf_counter()` is better suited

Comment: Oh interesting, I haven't seen that used much, why is that better suited?

Comment: `perf_counter` includes time passed in sleeps, is system-wide and has way better precision. Also if floating point rounds are an issue `perf_counter_ns` may be better. Take a look at (https://www.webucator.com/article/python-clocks-explained/)

Comment: oooh super cool, thanks matteo!

Answer (score 0):

- if you need quick result and dataset is very large like ~10GB
- and your lines in files in same order which means they are sorted.
  you can try this:

```
time diff --color file1.csv file2.csv
```

should be sufficient. just an alternate way for memory efficiency.